# How to disable copy/paste option in UITextfield in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I tried

```
@implementation UITextField (DisableCopyPaste)

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

return NO;
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
 }

@end
```

But it disables all textfield's copy/paste option,how to disable the menu options for specific textfield.

Comment: Are you using category for UITextField? If yes means, If you add that category in your view controller then all text fields created in that view controller don't have copy paste options.

Comment: Yes,i understand ,but the textfields in other view controllers too are not having that option

Comment: So you want to disable copy paste option for particular text field right in the same view controller?

Comment: If you import that text field category in your VC then all textfields created in the VC don't have copy paste option

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this method is ok,since no making of category etc.It works fine for me.

```
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] setMenuVisible:NO animated:NO];
    }];
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
```

Answer (score 9):

You should subclass `UITextView` and override `canPerformAction:withSender`.
Text fields that shouldn't provide copy/paste should be defined with your subclass.

*NonCopyPasteField.h:*

```
@interface NonCopyPasteField : UITextField
@end
```

*NonCopyPasteField.m:*

```
@implemetation
  (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copy:) || action == @selector(paste:)) {
      return NO;
    }
    [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
  }
@end
```

Update.
Swift version:

```
class NonCopyPasteField: UITextField {
  override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:))) {
      return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
  }
}
```

Comment: @JayprakashDubey I've updated answer with swift code

Answer (score 3):

Create a sub class for UITextField and overwrite the method and use it wherever you want.

```
@interface CustomTextField: UITextField
@end

@implemetation CustomTextField
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    //Do your stuff
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation you have to check if the sender is your exact textfield which should be disabled:

```
@implementation UITextField (DisableCopyPaste)

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if ((UITextField *)sender == yourTextField)
        return NO;

    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:self];
}

@end
```

But it is not good to make a category which overrides a method. It is better if you make a new class like `SpecialTextField` which inherits `UITextField` which will have the method always `return NO` for canPerformAction:withSender: and set this class to only the textfields which should have copy/paste disabled.

Comment: it is a terrible idea to override a method in a category. recommending such thing is another sin.

Comment: I am not recommending it and you will notice it is you read the whole answer. The first part of the answer is to point how to check for the exact text field which should have copy/paste disabled, as @SMS asked!

Comment: even if you do not recommend it, why did you think that someone else would use it? I guess, this horrible suggestion deserves the downvotes anyway.

Comment: If you have read the original question, you would have noticed that this is the way @SMS started it, so I just wanted to point him to the way to check for the exact text field. I do not get why you put so many efforts in just downvoting me instead of answering the question which is much more valuable.