# How to unhide UITextView's Edit Menu after tapping a menu item in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uitextview, edit

I have an Edit Menu in my `UITextView` selection to play an audio as shown below (see the screen shot). After i tap on play the Edit menu is hidden (I know its Apple's default behavior). I need to to retain the Edit menu even after tapping the play item and also want to change the text from play to stop. I hope some one can help me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: i have similar question.  i could not find solution, but am thinking of another way that may be good enough:  
.. disable the textview edit menu  
.. create your own menu (that you can choose to continue showing after tap, and change button label from 'play' to 'stop'  
  
the following stackoverlow answers were helpful and related to textview edit menu:  
.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426731/how-disable-copy-cut-select-select-all-in-uitextview  
.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115269/how-to-disable-copy-paste-option-in-uitextfield-in-ios7